# Не могу заставить работать библиотеку click

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

Имеется вот такой код:

```
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command("stats")
@click.argument("lat")
def stats_cli(lat):
    click.echo(f"{lat}")
```

Написал, чтоб чисто проверить, как работает. Мне известно, что Click сама генерирует Инструкции при запуске файла. По идее, я должен в терминале запустить файл с этим кодом, и он мне напишет инструкции. Но этого не происходит. Он вообще ничего не пишет. При запуске файла через команду

```
(venv) D:\Documents\weather>python weather\cli\cli.py
```

Терминал просто спускается на строку вниз и снова пишет

```
(venv) D:\Documents\weather>_
```

Для убедительности в том, что путь к файлу верный:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему не работает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашел свою ошибку.
В конце этого кода надо было дописать вызов функции `cli()`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```